# How to represent a set of non-ascii characters in Python's regex?

Tags: python, regex

In Python's regex, I found that `[一三四五六七八九十]` will not match a character which can be any in the brackets. But `一` will match itself exactly, and similarly for any other character in the brackets. How can I specify a regex  correctly to match any character in the brackets of `[一三四五六七八九十]`? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, then the key is `'\['`.

Comment: Because this is likely a problem with text versus bytes, please edit the question to show a specific example and a specific Python version.

Answer (score 2):

In *Python 3*, this appears to work OK, likely because strings are *Unicode* by default in *Python 3*.

The following code returns **一**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re

m = re.match("[一三四五六七八九十]", "一");

print(m.group(0))
```

However, if I run it in Python 2, I get an error:

> SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe4' in file ./re_multibyte.py on
>   line 5, but no encoding declared; see
>   http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

So for *Python 2*, you need to specify *UTF-8* as the source encoding as well as specify that the strings are unicode (via the `u` prefix), like so, and also get a match of **一**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# encoding: UTF-8

import re

m = re.match(u"[一三四五六七八九十]", u"一");

print(m.group(0))
```